# Bind property we cannot change

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Suppose we have class `User`, some properties like this:

```
public class User{
    public string Name{get;set;};

    public int Age{get;set;};
}
```

Due to some reason, we cannot modify the User(to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`), but we want to bind to the user's name. So if the name changed somewhere(not by us, means changes we may not very clear when or where, but we know it would happen), the UI can be changed too.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: You could write a wrapper class which does implement INotifyPropertyChanged and interact with the User that way. Also, those are fields rather than properties.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Sorry, it's mistaken in writing...

Answer (score 0):

You bind to the value, marking it `OneWay` so it cannot be pushed to the ViewModel.

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=User.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

and then your User's Name is set up in the ViewModel so that it can be set/changed whenever that mysterious *somewhere* does work.  So when the ViewModel is updated, the View will be alerted to it.  Can have the INotifyPropertyChanged either on the Model or ViewModel.

```
public class User
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if(name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bland, but maybe you misunderstood my question, I cannot modify the `User` class. And from @EsotericScreenName comment, I have solved my problem, just wrap a new class, it works.